# Output of a pointer program

Tags: c, pointers

I know little about pointers.

I came across the following program. The output seems normal but what is actually going going on I could not figure it out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
     int k;
     int a[] = {1,2,3}; int *b[3] ; int **c[3];
     int ***d[3]; int ****e[3]; int*****f[3];
     for (k = 0 ; k <3; k++)
     {
         b[k] = a + k; c[k] = b + k ; d[k] = c + k;
         e[k] = d + k ; f[k] = e + k;

     }
     for (k = 0 ; k <3; k++)
     {
        printf("%3d", *b[k]); printf("%3d", **c[k]);
        printf("%3d", ***d[k]); printf("%3d", ****e[k]);
        printf("%3d\n", *****f[k]);
     }
}
```

Comment: is this homework or someone trying to mess with you?beat that guy up and then answer him:-)

Comment: I found this on the Old questions of Engineering Exam

Comment: yeah that explains:-)

Comment: I found this on the Old questions of Engineering Exam

Comment: hmm its k that you have asked but sadly people are hated if they use such in production code. so i asked you. which exam by the way?

Comment: BE Computer Examination of 1st Year Here in Nepal...

Comment: i remember too in my exam i had got `i = ++i + i++ + --i + i++` :-) i dint answer and good for me standard says it UB:-)

Comment: For the record, this is obfuscated goo written by a bad programmer. Trying to figure out what it does yields little of value. On the contrary, chances are that staring at this code will make you a _worse_ programmer, if you decide to adopt any of this nonsense into your own programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `for` loop is just basic pointer arithmetic. `a[]` holds `int`s, each array after that holds a pointer.

`b[]` is a pointer to `int`

`c[]` is a pointer to pointer to `int`

etc

So it's something like this in memory:

```
Memory Address:      0x00441234 <---+   0x00441238 <----+     0x0044123C <---+
                     **********     |   **********      |     **********     |
var name:            * a (+0) *     |   * a (+1) *      |     * a (+2) *     |
                     **********     |   **********      |     **********     |
value:               *   1    *     |   *   2    *      |     *   3    *     |
                     **********     |   **********      |     **********     |
                                    |                   |                    |
                                    |                   |                    |
                  +-> 0x00442345    | +->0x00442349     | +->0x0044234D      |
                  |   ************  | |  ************   | |  ************    |
                  |   *  b (+0)  *  | |  *  b (+1)  *   | |  * b  (+2)  *    |
                  |   ************  | |  ************   | |  ************    |
                  |   *0x00441234* -+ |  *0x00441238* --+ |  *0x0044123C*  --+
                  |   ************    |  ************     |  ************     
                  |                   |                   |
                  |                   |                   |
                  |   0x00443345      | 0x00443349        | 0x0044334D      
                  |   ************    | ************      | ************    
                  |   *  c (+0)  *    | *  c (+1)  *      | * c  (+2)  *    
                  |   ************    | ************      | ************    
                  +-- *0x00442345*    +-*0x00442349*      +-*0x0044234D* 
                      ************      ************        ************
```

And each element of `D` points to each element of `C`, and so on. The end result being you're setting each element in each of the arrays (via some chain of pointers) back to the elements of `a`. And then in the second `for` loop you're printing the elements of `a[]` over and over again.

Comment: do you 5-6 arms? and 5-6 keyboards?:-)

Comment: @Koushik He probably has [this](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw). ;)

Comment: @SuvP - Actually I just have copy and paste. :D That is a nice link, that'll save some time! Thanks!

Comment: @Mike U must be a patient ASCII artist, to do that graph with an editor ;) :D

Answer (score 1):

```
     int k;
     int a[] = {1,2,3}; //array of 3 ints
     int *b[3] ; //array of 3 integer pointers
     int **c[3]; //array of 3 integer double pointers
     int ***d[3]; //array of 3 pointers to integer double pointers
     int ****e[3]; //array of 3 pointers to pointers to integer double pointers
     int*****f[3]; //array of 3 pointers to  pointers to pointers to integer double    pointers
     for (k = 0 ; k <3; k++)
     {
         b[k] = a + k; 
          //a gives base address to array a 
          //Add k to it and store it in b[k]. Note, this isn't normal arithmetic its 
          //pointer aritmetic 
         c[k] = b + k ; 
         d[k] = c + k;
         e[k] = d + k ; 
         f[k] = e + k;
     }
     for (k = 0 ; k <3; k++)
     {
        printf("%3d", *b[k]); //dereference single level pointer
        printf("%3d", **c[k]); //dereference second level pointer 
        printf("%3d", ***d[k]); printf("%3d", ****e[k]);
        printf("%3d\n", *****f[k]);
     }
```

You can have any number of level of pointers. i.e pointer to (pointer to (pointer ...)) and so on [upto a limit defined by standards]

For an interesting read, see [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happening:

You define a variable `k`  of datatype `int`

You define an array , `a` having values, `1, 2, 3`

You defined an  array of pointers, `b`

You defined an  array of pointers to pointers, `c`

.................................and similar upto `f`

You iterated from 0 to 2, and assigned values to `b`, `c`, `d`, .... upto `f`

You again iterated from 0 to 2 and printed:

The value pointed by each element in `b`, `c`,..... upto `f`

**EDIT**: What happened b[k] = a + k, is you went forward k blocks in your memory, whose address was assigned to b[k], So, b[k] points to that block in your memory,( which may be any value)

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand what is `b[k] = a + k` doing. rest are the same.

`a[]` is an array with 3 elements `1, 2, and 3` and `a` itself refer to the `0th` element of the array, i.e `a` is the address of the 1st element of the array.

now `a + k`, in pointer arithmetic, represents the `kth` element of the array named `a`.

So, consider the 1st pass of the loop, and k = 0.

Your 1st statement becomes `b[0] = a + 0`. Notice `a + 0` is an address, and it is being contained by an element of `b`. So, `b` should be of the type `int *`, and in your code it is declared as `int *b[3]`.

And for `c[0] = b + 0`, you are storing an `address of address of int`, so `c` is declared as double pointer `int **c[3]`.

Now these things happen to every array you use, just with an extra level of pointer. That means, you are holding the address of the elements of the previous array.